# Construct a Ruby object that returns the names of methods called on it

Tags: ruby, string, metaprogramming

I want to construct a Ruby object that has the following property: For any method name, when that method name is passed to the object, the return value is the method name as a string.

Here is an attempt that has a few problems:

```
class Echo < BasicObject
  def self.method_missing(the_method)
    the_method.to_s
  end
end
```

`Echo` responds to most method calls as desired:

```
> Echo.foo
 => "foo" 
> Echo.send("Hello world.")
=> "Hello world."
```

But `Echo` inherits from `BasicObject` and so it responds in the normal way to its superclass' methods:

```
> Echo.to_s
=> "Echo"
```

How can I construct an object that *always* echoes back the messages its passed. (Bonus points if the solution doesn't require complex method lookups on every call.)

Comment: If you want to know whether your solution is efficient, you just need to follow 4 easy steps: 1) define *precisely* what you mean by "efficient", 2) define *precisely* what the exact threshold is, i.e. which numbers are still efficient and which ones aren't according to your definition from #1, 3) write a statistically significant, repeatable, automated, objective, meaningful benchmark, 4) run it and see whether the result is over or under your threshold from #2. If you want to know whether you can do better, you need to first precisely define what you mean by "better".

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've edited the question to remove talk of efficiency. I think you were being uncharitable when you claimed not to know what I meant by "better". I clearly stated the desired behavior and provided a case (`#to_s`) for which my attempt didn't conform to that behavior. I think it was pretty clear that a better solution would be one that doesn't permit counterexamples, or at least permits fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class Echo
  class << self
    def method_missing(the_method)
      the_method.to_s
    end

    methods.each do |name|
      define_method(name) do |*any|
        name.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Tests:

```
RSpec.describe Echo do
  it "returns a missing method as a string" do
    expect(described_class.some_method_that_doesnt_exist).
      to eq("some_method_that_doesnt_exist")
  end

  it "returns an existing method as a string" do
    expect(described_class.to_s).
      to eq("to_s")
  end
end
```